# Does Android “Installs targeted by rollout” refer to the percentage of users able to SEE update or able to INSTALL update?

Tags: android, google-play, release, rollout

I have uploaded a new version of my Android App I have released to the app store. Currently I am rolling it out slowly, using the "Update Rollout" feature on the Google Play-store. The app has been heavily tested, but wanted to test what the migration from previous versions was like for users before full deployment.

Currently the "Installs targeted by rollout" percentage is set to 50%, I have well less than that in the "Installs on active devices".

Does this mean:

**50% of my users can see the update, regardless of installs**

***OR***

**All my users  can see my updated version until the first 50% install**

I am asking as I have a  particular user encountering issues with a previous version and their phone specifically, which will likely be helped by this latest release. However - the rollout can't "target" specific users.

---

Here is the [official documentation from Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en) on staged rollouts. These were the main points on the users but I couldn't quite if the "targeted value" was a targeted percentage of users on this version, or percentage of users who could download the upgrade.

- New and existing users are eligible to receive updates from staged
  rollouts and are chosen at random for each new release rollout.
- Your app update will be available to the percentage of users in your staged rollout, but it may take time for the full group to receive the update.

---

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, that if you set rollout to `50%`, `50% of existing` (active) users will get the update and also `50% of new installs` will get the last version directly.

Which also makes sense in means of testing (it's important to see if the version behaves correctly during initial install or update).